# Is that sentence is correct

Tags: adverbs

I wonder that following sentence is correct way to use?

```
It is updated as the user inputs new information.
```

Does **As** adverb is used in right way in that sentence?

Or Do I have to use this sentence like:

```
It is updated when the user inputs new information.
```

So which one is more formal?

Thanks

Comment: This would be a good question at [ell.se] because it is a request for writing advice and because of the type of expert needed. The OP needs an expert English teacher rather than a linguist or etymologist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"as" implies that it is updated at the same time as the user is entering the information.
"when" can have the same meaning as "as" but can also mean after the user has finished inputting the information.

see also the [ell stackexchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/as-a-child-vs-when-i-was-a-child)

Comment: I switched your link to a specific ELL question covering *when/as* usages. There are probably others even more specific to OP's question here, but it's actually surprisingly difficult to search for relevant questions with only the words **when as**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As opposed to [whenas](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whenas)?

Comment: @Elliott: Indeed. **Whereas** it's easy to establish there are [no ELU questions about the single word **"whenas"**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com+%22whenas%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com+%22whenas%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.21519480j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) (provided you put it in **"quotes"**), you just get tons of irrelevant hits when you search for the two separate words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The same search for ["when as"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fenglish.stackexchange.com+%22when+as%22) returns ~169 results.

Comment: @Elliott: I've long felt that [titles should be standardised where possible](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/), but in three years not a single person has seen fit to upvote and indicate approval for even such an obvious "template" standard as **[wordA] vs [WordB]**, so I guess I'm flogging a dead horse there. So although you won't get any results from a Google site-specific search for **"when vs as"**, it's still at least *feasible* there are several questions on that very point. And I'm not wading through 169 results to (inconclusively) establish the truth of the matter!

Answer (score 0):

The word "as" introduces a clause, so it is a conjunction and not an adverb.
I would prefer "when" or "whenever". "as" is a multifunction word and it may happen that a reader has to read your sentence two times to get the structure clear, especially as you have two words, "user" and "inputs" that can be taken for nouns at the first reading. On second reading one understands that "inputs" is a verb form.